# $ABCD$ is a trapezoid. If $AB=AD=AC=a$, $BD=b$, find the length of the other leg $BC$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$ABCD$ is a trapezoid. If $AB=AD=AC=a$, $BD=b$, find the length of the other leg $BC$.
[image]
There are a few isosceles triangles on the diagram - $\triangle ABC,\triangle ABD,\triangle ACD$. I have tried to do some angle calculations. If $\measuredangle ABD=\measuredangle ADB=\alpha\Rightarrow \measuredangle BDC=\alpha$. What next?

Comment: Hint: Drop perp from $A$ to $BD$ and foot of the perp is $H$. Also, drop a perp from $A$ to $BC$ with foot of the perp as $G$. Can you see $\triangle ADH \cong \triangle CAG$ and hence $BC = 2 AH$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\angle CAD=2\alpha$, by the cosine rule we have:

$b^2=2a^2-2a^2\cos(\pi/2+\alpha)=2a^2(1+\sin\alpha)$

and:

$BC^2=2a^2-2a^2\cos(\pi/2-\alpha)=2a^2(1-\sin\alpha)$.

Adding those two relations you get $BC^2=4a^2-b^2$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify for me the first cosine rule?

Comment: I cannot quite see where the angle $90^\circ+\alpha$ comes from. Which triangle?

Comment: Drop from $A$ the perpendicular $AH$ to $CD$, which is also the bisector of $\angle CAD$.

Comment: I still don't see how this makes $\measuredangle BAD$ equal to $90^\circ+\alpha$.

Comment: $\angle BAH=90°$, $\angle HAD=\alpha$.

Comment: $\cos(90^\circ+\alpha)=-\sin\alpha$, right... So isn't $b^2=2a^2(1+\sin\alpha)$?

Comment: So isn't $b^2=2a^2(1+\sin\alpha)$?

Comment: You are right: I've corrected both equalities. But the final result doesn't change.

Comment: I don't see how we "add" the two relations to get $BC^2=4a^2-b^2$. Thank you.

Comment: That's the final result, of course: you are supposed to use some algebra.

Answer (score 0):

This is a re-engineered result based on the solution given by @IntelligentiPauca.

[image]

For some reason, we first draw BX perpendicular to BD and let it cut DC extended at X.

Let M be the midpoint of DX so that M is the center of the circle passing through D, B, and X. Thus, MX = MD = MB and $\angle 1= \angle 2$.

Also, $\angle 1= \angle 2 = \angle 3 = \angle =4$ implies ABMD is a parallelogram. In fact, ABMD is a rhombus [because AD = AB = a]. This means

(1) ABXM is a parallelogram [because AM is perpendicular to DB]; and

(2) ABMC is an isosceles trapezium [because MB = MX = MD = DA = AC].

From (2), $\angle ABC = \alpha = \beta = \gamma = \delta$. Therefore BX = BC.

Applying Pythagoras to $\triangle DBX$, we have $b^2 + (BC)^2 = (2a)^2$.